# Angular and working with a "core" route param (i.e. like Account ID / Subscription ID)

Tags: angular

I have been working on trying to get a route setup working that would enforce and ID at the start of every route.
i.e.

- {domain.com}/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/setup
- {domain.com}/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/
- {domain.com}/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/dashboard

I can set up a route like this:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ":accountId",
    component: Layout2Component,
    pathMatch: "full",
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
    children: [{ path: "", component: DashboardComponent }],
  },
  {
    path: ":accountId/documentation",
    component: Layout2Component,
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import("./modules/documentation/documentation.module").then((m) => m.DocumentationModule),
  },
```

and then in my app.component.ts:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
  if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    const urlSplit = e.url.split("/");
    this.accountId = urlSplit[1];
    this.initialiseAccount();
  }
});
```

This works, however there the issue is that everywhere I put route/links I need to manually prefix the accountId {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} to URLs.

Is there a better way?

The other thing (less issue), is that I need to put :accountId in each of my routes.  I tried using child routes like below - but it just didn't recognise any of the child routes.  Any idea?

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ":accountId",
    component: Layout2Component,
    pathMatch: "full",
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: "documentation",
        pathMatch: "full",
        canActivate: [MsalGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import("./modules/documentation/documentation.module").then((m) => m.DocumentationModule),
      },
```

Comment: For now I have done this way, and just put the accountId manually in all menus for now, as couldn't find an automated way.